# $x$-derivative of the wave function and its conjugate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, differentiation, calculus

I saw that in order to show that the normalisability of a wave function does not depend on time, there is a necessary step in the calculation that says that:
$$\left(\Psi^*\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2\Psi^*}{\partial x^2}\Psi\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\Psi^*\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi\right)$$

Why is this true? I'm guessing it's because the $x$ derivatives of $\Psi$ and $\Psi^*$ cancel, but why is that the case?

Comment: Could the users voting to close this as "unclear" comment on what they think is unclear about it?

Comment: I voted to close this post as unclear: I do not understand if the issue simply  regards a derivative of a product of functions or there is something concerning physics. In the first case, PSE is not the right place to post it, in my view. Maybe the reason “unclear” was inappropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) on the RHS,
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\Psi^*\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi\right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\Psi^*\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}\Psi\right) \\
&=\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}+\Psi^*\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\left[\frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2}\Psi+\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}\right] \\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}}+\Psi^*\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 \Psi^*}{\partial x^2}\Psi \underbrace{-\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}}
\end{align}
The first and last terms are identical but there's a negative sign attached to the second one, hence the two terms cancel.